# Settings Selector Dynamically in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table whose values are being generated dynamically with PHP, including the id and name attributes (e.g. id="question_".

How can I set an element attribute with this in mind? For example, I have a div whose text will change after a successful ajax call, but the id is dynamic.

I have tried making the following test function, and calling it on an onclick event:

```
function approve(question_id)
{
    var div = 'suggestion_status_' + question_id;
    $('#div').html('test');
}
```

But that does not work.  How can make the value of variable 'div' the selector?

Comment: Wow, I figured it out immediately after posting this.

     $('#suggestion_status_' + question_id).html('test');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this. $('#suggestion_status_' + question_id).html('test');
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your example is that `div` is a variable, not a string; so the following will work:

```
function approve(question_id)
{
    var div = 'suggestion_status_' + question_id;
    $('#' + div).html('test');
}
```

Or even:

```
function approve(question_id)
{
    $('#suggestion_status_' + question_id).html('test');
}
```

Another approach would be to utilize classes, and add a known class to your elements. Without seeing the full HTML, I can't provide a full example, but *something* like this would be the way to go:

```
$('.yourCommonClass').bind('click', function () {
    var that = this;

    jQuery.get('/accept.php', {
        id: this.id
    }, function (msg) {
        $(that).html('Accepted!');
    });
});
```

Bearing in mind that [`jQuery.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get) parameters are the target url, optional data attributes that are encoded in the request, and then a callback function.

Answer (score 1):

you defined div as a variable then used it as a string try concatenating it instead

```
function approve(question_id)
{
    var div = 'suggestion_status_' + question_id;
    $('#'+ div).html('test');
}
```

or shorten like this

```
function approve(question_id)
{
    $('#suggestion_status_' + question_id).html('test');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#suggestion_status_' + question_id).html('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#suggestion_status_' + question_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
function approve(question_id)
{
    var div = 'suggestion_status_' + question_id;
    $('#'+div).html('test');
}
```